# Visual Aspect changing when i change windows theme

Tags: c#

after running my application.exe i noticed that when  i change the windows xp theme (for example from normal to classical) the visual aspect of my application changes!Can someone please tell me what should i do to make a static GUI that doesn't change when i change the theme or switch from Windows xp to Windows 7 
Ps: i'm working on .NET Framework 4

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: You shouldn't try to fight against the OS theme, unless you're writing a GUI completely from scratch. Users prefer applications that are consistent with the programs that run beside them.

Comment: Hi Bradley! thank you for the quick response! i am in the final phase of creating my PC application, and then i was asked to run the executable under different OS (windows XP/vista/seven) with different themes to make sure my application's visual aspect doesn't change, but what i've found is that event my application's button change of aspect, for example with other known application as MICROSOFT OFFICE WORD the visual aspect doesn't change, how can i do that?????

Comment: Hello Nicolas! i am using Windows Forms application,thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The UI look is changing because windows theme changes the default fonts which change the number of points needed for their rendering.

open the visual studio with the default theme then change it and debug the winform you'll see how the controls change sizes...

read this msdn article it might help you decide what to do next [Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605.aspx)